# How does this swig code look like in jade?

Tags: express, pug, swig

I am studying how to build meeting web application on express. In the lecture, he uses swig, but I prefer to use jade instead of swig since I am trying to get use to it.

I am trying to convert swig code to jade, I am stuck in these code.

```
//In swig, 
<div class="col-md-12 column list-group">{% for note in notes %}
          <div class="list-group-item">
            <div>Note from <em><strong>{{ note.memberName }}</strong></em>                  on: {{ note.createdOn.toDateString() }}
                                - for project: <strong>{{ note.project }}</strong>
            </div>
            <div><strong>Work yesterday:</strong> {{ note.workYesterday }}</div>
            <div><strong>Work today:</strong> {{ note.workToday }}</div>
            <div><strong>Impediment:</strong> {{ note.impediment }}</div>
          </div>              {% endfor %}
```

I guess `{% for note in notes %}` will be like `for note in notes` in jade file. however, I cannot convert other part such `{{note.project}}` and other codes start with `{{ note.`.

Can anyone help with it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Jade reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/) your foreach loop would look like this: `each note in notes`. And the properties of `note` should also be accessible as `note.project`. At least if they're Javascript objects.

Comment: Then, does it look like `strong note.project` ? I think then it will print `note.project` as content.

Comment: If you want to print the value of variables you use them like this `#{note.project}`. So in combination with the `strong` tag it would be: `strong #{note.project}`